# How to display a text message instead of an image inside a table cell?

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic, grid

I am trying to display either an image or a message inside a table cell of the table. I am using classic ASP and SQL for database. The database has a column "imgName" for images. Now I have to display a table with these images if there are images. If there is no image, then I need to display "Image is not available." It is a simple if-else statement but its not working. Any comments or help are greatly appreciated. Piece of code inside while loop is shown below:

```
<%
    IF rs("imgName") = ""
        Response.Write "<tr><td>Image not available</td></tr>"
    ELSE
        Response.Write "<tr><td><a href='test.asp'><img src='http://cdn.example.com/images/40/"& rs("imgName") &"'></a></tr>"
    END IF
%>
```

Comment: Why it is not working? Does it goes inside the IF or only inside the ELSE?

Comment: Is it really a blank string if there's no image? Or is it NULL?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "but its not working".  What are the current results?

Comment: It goes to else statement only. so if there is no image for specific td it gives image box without image instead of "Image not available"

Comment: Your first line should be `IF rs("imgName") = "" then` - you've missed the "then"

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes to test if something is there or not I use IsNull, IsEmpty, and a test for "". Like this:

```
<%
    If Not rs("imgName") = "" And Not IsNull(rs("imgName")) And Not IsEmpty(rs("imgName")) Then
        Response.Write "<tr><td><a href='test.asp'><img src='http://cdn.example.com/images/40/"& rs("imgName") &"'></a></tr>"
    Else
        Response.Write "<tr><td>Image not available</td></tr>"            
    End If
%>
```

Comment: What should I get once i check for IsEmpty and IsNull? When I applied those, it gave me no change, I mean I got empty imgbox instead of the errormsg. It didn't go to if statement. when I checked in developer, it gave me 403 error. "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (forbidden)"

Comment: Missing a couple of closing brackets in `Or IsNull(rs("imgName") Or IsEmpty(rs("imgName") ` . Shouldn't it be `Or IsNull(rs("imgName")) Or IsEmpty(rs("imgName") )` ?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Yup you are correct. I had kept those closing brackets while testing :)

Comment: @LouManizer I've changed the logic around. Maybe try that. It always takes me a couple of tries to get it right.